# При повороте экрана запускается onCreate()

Tags: android, activity, activity-life-cycle

В процессе работы столкнулся со следующими трудностями (поиск решения в интернете результатов не дал).
При повороте экрана приложения запускается onCreate() из за чего сбрасываются ранее сделанные действия и приводит к неприятным ситуациям.
Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Пробовал добавить в манифест следующий код:

```
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize">
```

В этом случае не запускается layout-land тем самым идет неправильное отображение.

Comment: так и должно быть. при повороте активность пересоздается. если используете `android:configChanges` то пересоздания не будет, но и 2 варианта разметки не будут работать. если хотите и рыбку съесть и на сосне покататься - рекомендую смотреть в сторону MVVM и ViewModel

Comment: Для того, чтобы не происходили "неприятные ситуации" существует механизм сохранения/восстановления значений в/из Bundle.

Comment: Как это реализовать? где почитать?